# Secret Santa with Groups on Swift

Tags: algorithm, swift, shuffle

I am working on an special version of Secret Santa with internal sub-groups.

Typical Secret Santa (SS) requirements:

- Cannot be assigned to themselves
- Should be random
- Every participant should be assigned to someone
- Every participant should have someone assigned to

Special requirements; there are subgroups that should be taken into consideration:

- Reduce participants assigned to someone into their same group as much as possible (none if possible)

## Implementation

I am new to Swift, I am working on a playground.  Let's first consider the problems to solve:

### Problems to consider

#### For one group (normal SS)

Let's assume a 3 people group

```
1->2
2->1
3->?
```

In that case there is no possible person for 3 to give to.

#### For multiple groups

Assume these 3 groups `group-participant`:

```
[1-1,1-2]
[2-1]
[3-1]
```

This could be assigned like this

```
2-1 -> 3-1
3-1 -> 2-1
1-1 -> 1->2
1-2 -> 1->1
```

Which is not a desired outcome.

### Algorithm

Pick random participant `p` from all the possible participants.  Also save the first `p` apart.

```
if p is not from the largest group
    r is a random element from the largest group
else if p is from the largest group and there are multiple non-empty groups
    r is a random element from the any other group
else if p is not from the largest group and is from the only remaining group
    r is a random element from its group that it is not p
p gives present to r
```

Now remove `p` from the groups and repeat the same but make `p=r` until it is there are no more participants.  The last one gives to the first one and the shuffle is complete.

### Code

```
            class Participant: CustomStringConvertible {
        var name = "noname"
        var contact = "nocontact"
        var giveTo:Participant?
        init(name:String,contact:String){
            self.name = name
            self.contact = contact
        }
        var description: String {return name + ((giveTo==nil) ?"":"->\(giveTo!.name)")}
    }

    class Group: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
        static var allGroups:[Group]=[]
        static var counter = 0
        var participants:[Participant]=[]
        var name = "G-x"
        var description:String {return name}
        var debugDescription:String {return name}
        init(participants:[Participant]){
            self.participants=participants
            name = "G-\(Group.counter++)"
            Group.allGroups.append(self)
            Group.allGroups = Group.sortGroups(Group.allGroups)
        }

        func size()->Int{return self.participants.count}

        func getRandParticipant()->Participant{
            let p = participants[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(participants.count)))]
            return p
        }

        func remove(p:Participant)->Bool{
            let originalIndex = participants.count
            participants = participants.filter() { $0.name != p.name }
            return originalIndex != participants.count
        }

        static func sortGroups(g:[Group])->[Group]{
            //remove groups with size = 0
            let rg = g.filter() {return $0.size()>0}
            //sort
            return rg.sort() {return $0.0.size()>$0.1.size()}
        }

        static func getRandGroup(groups:[Group])->Group{
            return groups[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(groups.count)))]
        }

        static func removeFromGroups(groups:[Group],p:Participant)->[Group]{
            for g in groups{
                if(g.remove(p)){
                    break;
                }
            }
            return sortGroups(groups)
        }

        static func getPairs(groups:[Group])->[Participant]{
            var groups2consume = groups
            var giverGroup = getRandGroup(groups2consume)
            var searchIn:[Group]
            var giver:Participant = giverGroup.getRandParticipant()
            let first = giver
            var returnArray:[Participant] = []
            while(groups2consume.count>0){
                let indexO = groups2consume.indexOf() {$0.name==giverGroup.name}
                if let index = indexO{
                    if (index>0){
                        //if giverGroup is 0 it means it is in the largest group
                        searchIn = [groups2consume[0]]
                    }else if groups2consume.count>1{
                        //if giverGroup is not 0 and the count is >0 then there are smaller groups
                        searchIn = groups2consume
                        searchIn.removeFirst()
                    }else{
                        //there is only one group left
                        searchIn = groups2consume
                        searchIn[0].remove(giver)
                    }
                    if searchIn[0].participants.count>0{
                        let receiverGroup = getRandGroup(searchIn)
                        let receiver = receiverGroup.getRandParticipant()
                        groups2consume = removeFromGroups(groups2consume, p: giver)
                        giver.giveTo=receiver
                        returnArray.append(giver)
                        giverGroup = receiverGroup
                        giver = receiver
                    }else{
                        groups2consume = removeFromGroups(groups2consume, p: giver)
                    }
                }else{
                    break
                }
            }
            giver.giveTo=first
            returnArray.append(giver)
            return returnArray
        }
    }
```

### Test

```
    Group(participants:[
        Participant(name: "p1", contact: "n1"),
        Participant(name: "p2", contact: "n2"),
        Participant(name: "p3", contact: "n3"),
        Participant(name: "p4", contact: "n4"),
        Participant(name: "p5", contact: "n5")])

    Group(participants:[
        Participant(name: "p1", contact: "n1")])


    Group(participants:[
        Participant(name: "p1", contact: "n1"),
        Participant(name: "p2", contact: "n2")])

    Group.allGroups

    let pairs = Group.getPairs(Group.allGroups);
    print("pairs(\(pairs.count))  done \(pairs)")
```

### Output

```
pairs(8)  done [p1->p1, p1->p4, p4->p2, p2->p2, p2->p1, p1->p3, p3->p5, p5->p1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works – as far as I can see – correctly. I cannot judge
the fairness of the algorithm itself, but I have some suggestions
concerning the implementation.

My first point of criticism is the use of the static `Group` property
`allGroups`:

- Each created `Group` instance is implicitly appended to `allGroups` which
  is not obvious to the user of your code. The call `Group(participants:[...])`
  creates a group and discards the result (which gives a compiler warning),
  so the initializer is called purely for its side effect.
- It makes the code less reusable. You cannot create an independent second
  set of groups.

I would suggest to build an array of groups explicitly:

```
let g1 = Group(participants:[...])
let g2 = Group(participants:[...])
let g3 = Group(participants:[...])
let allGroups = [g1, g2, g3]
```

Similarly, the static `Group` property `counter` is used to assign
consecutive names to the each created group. This is acceptable, but why
not create each group with an explicit name (as you already do for the
participants)?

```
let g1 = Group(name: "G1", participants:[...])
let g2 = Group(name: "G2", participants:[...])
let g3 = Group(name: "G3", participants:[...])
```

There is too much logic in the `Group` class. In fact all the *static* methods
are used for the "Secret Santa" algorithm, and do not use any state of
the `Group` class. I suggest to create a separate
class for that purpose:

```
let g1 = Group(name: "G1", participants:[...])
let g2 = Group(name: "G2", participants:[...])
let g3 = Group(name: "G3", participants:[...])

let santa = SecretSanta(groups: [g1, g2, g3])
let pairs = santa.assignPairs()
print(pairs)
```

Now lets have a look at the `Participant` class. There is no need to assign
default initial values "noname", "nocontact" because both properties are
assigned to in the init method. Moreover, name and contact do never change,
so they can be constant properties with `let`:

```
class Participant {
    let name : String
    let contact : String
    var giveTo : Participant?

    init(name: String, contact: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.contact = contact
    }
}
```

For better structuring of the code, protocol implementations such as
 `CustomStringConvertible` can be written as an extension.
Testing against `nil` and implicit unwrapping should be avoided in favor
of optional binding:

```
extension Participant: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var desc = name
        if let receiver = giveTo {
            desc += " -> " + receiver.name
        }
        return desc
    }
}
```

or more compactly using the `Optional.map()` method:

```
extension Participant: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        return name + (giveTo.map { " -> " + $0.name } ?? "")
    }
}
```

In the `remove()` method of `Group` the name of the participant is used
to identify it in an array. This is error-prone because it relies on unique
names. A better solution is to implement the `Equatable` protocol, so that
participants can be compared with `==`. Since `Participant` is a class,
i.e. a reference type, this can  be done with the "identical-to"
operator `===`, i.e. only identical instances are considered equal:

```
extension Participant : Equatable { }

func ==(lhs : Participant, rhs : Participant) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}
```

Now a simple `participants.indexOf(p)` can be used to find a participant
in an array.

The same suggestions apply to the `Group` class. If we remove the
static properties and methods, this is what it could look like:

```
class Group {

    let name : String
    var participants: [Participant]

    init(name: String, participants: [Participant]) {
        self.name = name
        self.participants = participants
    }

    var size : Int {
        return participants.count
    }

    func randomParticipant() -> Participant {
        precondition(participants.count > 0, "participants array is empty")
        return participants[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size)))]
    }

    func removeParticipant(participant : Participant) {
        guard let index = participants.indexOf(participant) else {
            fatalError("participant not found in group")
        }
        participants.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}

extension Group : CustomStringConvertible {

    var description : String { return name }
}

extension Group : Equatable { }

func ==(lhs : Group, rhs : Group) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}
```

- I have made `size` a computed property instead of a function, similar to
  `count` for arrays or `length` for strings.
- In `getRandParticipant()` I have removed the "get" prefix which should not
  be used. In addition, a precondition is added to detect programming errors.
- `remove()` is renamed to `removeParticipant()` and *expects* that the
  participant is present in the array. Instead of filtering the array, 
  `indexOf` and `removeAtIndex` are used as a small optimization.

The remaining logic is moved to a `SecretSanta` class:

```
class SecretSanta {

    var remainingGroups : [Group]

    init(groups : [Group]) {
        // Make a copy of the group list:
        self.remainingGroups = groups.map { Group(name: $0.name, participants: $0.participants) }
    }

    // ....

    func assignPairs() -> [Participant] { ... }
}
```

The init method makes a copy of all groups, so that the algorithm can freely remove
participants without modifying the original groups.

Your

```
static func sortGroups(g:[Group])->[Group]
static func getRandGroup(groups:[Group])->Group
```

methods become  instance methods without parameters which operate directly
on the `remainingGroups` property:

```
func randomGroup() -> Group {
    precondition(remainingGroups.count > 0, "groups array is empty")
    return remainingGroups[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(remainingGroups.count)))]
}

func sortGroups() {
    // Remove groups without participants:
    remainingGroups = remainingGroups.filter { $0.size > 0 }
    // Sort by number of participants in decreasing order:
    remainingGroups.sortInPlace { $1.size < $0.size }
}
```

Note that you can omit the `return` statement in a single-expression closure.

Your

```
 static func removeFromGroups(groups:[Group],p:Participant)->[Group]
```

is not needed anymore. At each point in the algorithm, it is *known* to which
group a participant belongs, so there is no need to search it in a group
array. Also sorting the groups from within that method is confusing.

Using all that, the main Secret Santa method can be written as

```
func assignPairs() -> [Participant] {

    var sortedParticipants : [Participant] = []
    sortGroups()

    var giverGroup = randomGroup()
    var giver = giverGroup.randomParticipant()
    let firstGiver = giver

    while true {
        sortedParticipants.append(giver)
        giverGroup.removeParticipant(giver)

        guard let groupIndex = remainingGroups.indexOf(giverGroup) else {
            fatalError("group not found")
        }

        // Determine destination group:
        var receiverGroup : Group
        if groupIndex > 0 {
            // giver is not from the largest group(0)
            receiverGroup = remainingGroups[0]
        } else if remainingGroups.count > 1 {
            // giver is from the largest group(0), there is at least one other group
            repeat {
                receiverGroup = randomGroup()
            } while receiverGroup == giverGroup
        } else if remainingGroups[0].size > 0 {
            // There is only one group, but at least one receiver left
            receiverGroup = remainingGroups[0]
        } else {
            // This was the last giver
            giver.giveTo = firstGiver
            break
        }

        // Determine receiver in destination group and assign:
        let receiver = receiverGroup.randomParticipant()
        giver.giveTo = receiver

        // Prepare for next round:
        sortGroups()
        giverGroup = receiverGroup
        giver = receiver
    }

    return sortedParticipants
}
```

- I have called it `assignPairs` because it modifies the participants.
  A better name is surely possible.
- I have tried to write the code in a way that *I* understand it :)
- Removing the current "giver" from its group early in the loop makes things a little
  bit easier later.
- The extra groups array `searchIn` is not needed if we accept that in one
  case, several calls to `randomGroup()` are necessary. In the worst case
  (only 2 groups left) the average number of calls is 2.
- In your code, at

  ```
      let indexO = groups2consume.indexOf() {$0.name==giverGroup.name}
  ```

  `index0` is *expected* to be non-nil. It is better to abort with an error
  if that is no satisfied (to detect programming errors early) instead of
  "silently" breaking from the loop. Note also that

  ```
      remainingGroups.indexOf(giverGroup)
  ```

  takes advantage of the `Equatable` protocol which we implemented for `Group`,
  and does not rely on unique names anymore.

More suggestions:

- Remove the `giveTo` property from `Participants` to make the
  instances immutable, and return a list of pairs (e.g. tuples)
  instead.
- Add a check that the same participant is not added to more
  that one group (and `throw` an error if that happens). I did not check how that situation is handled in your
  code or my modification, but I don't expect it to work correctly.
- More whitespace – at least around operators and `{}` code blocks.

Comment: This is great, I will make some changes tomorrow and link to a second post (and accept your question then).  I really like all your suggestions, except the repeat part (I'll try to fix that).

Comment: @rr1g0: You mean the `while true ... break`? Yes, one can argue about that and I tried several variants. The problem was that you have to find recipients until only one group with one element is left, so `while groups.count > 0` did not work in my version. An alternative is to keep track of the number of remaining recipients and do `while remainingRecipients > 0`.

Comment: Actually I meant the other one, the `repeat ... while recieverGroup==giverGroup`.  I was thinking of removing the `randomGroups()` function altogether and just getting the random value on that line, that way the `repeat..while` is no longer needed; neither the `randomGroup` function.  And it is still obvious what it is doing.

Comment: Why is it better to use `extension` instead of the way I was doing it?

Comment: @rr1g0: It helps to organize the code into groups and makes it more clear that the method is there because of the protocol. Functionally, there is no difference.